# django datetimefield in abstract model cannot update "auto_now_add", "auto_now"

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I do a code with an abstract model for control create and update documents:

```
class Control(models.Model):
ctrl_dt_add = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
ctrl_dt_mod = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
ctrl_dt_del = models.DateTimeField(default=None,blank=True,null=True)
ctrl_user_add = models.OneToOneField( 
    to=User,
    on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
    default=None,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)
ctrl_user_mod = models.OneToOneField( 
    to=User,
    on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
    default=None,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)
ctrl_user_del = models.OneToOneField( 
    to=User,
    on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
    default=None,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)
ctrl_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False) 

class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

And my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
_id = models.ObjectIdField()
..........
control = models.EmbeddedField(
    model_container = Control,
    model_form_class = ControlForm
)
objects = models.DjongoManager()

class Meta:
    db_table = 'mymodel'

def __str__(self):
    return self.value
```

My problem is, when i create a new document with this model, control key insert in all datetime keys a null value like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5f04a3ecc108e12ca4bf5a7f"),
    ............
"control" : {
    "ctrl_dt_add" : null,
    "ctrl_dt_mod" : null,
    "ctrlwdt_del" : null,
    "ctrl_user_add_id" : 1,
    "ctrl_user_mod_id" : null,
    "ctrl_user_del_id" : null,
    "ctrl_deleted" : false
}
```

}

I need to declare values in all the actions with this model.
I save it creating a save function in the model. But i would like to do not need that for work with it.

```
def save(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if request:
        self.control.ctrl_user_mod = request.user
        self.control.ctrl_dt_mod = now()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thank you!!